# PHP login form and logout button not showing properly

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I just started learning PHP and am having some trouble getting a simple login page to work. When I load this script the first time, the text "Wrong password/username." and the logout button are printed but not the login form. Why is this happening, and how would I change the code to make the login form and logout button work together as expected?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['log_out'])) { // If the page was reloaded as a result of the user having clicked the logout button,
session_destroy(); // kill session.
}

session_start(); // Start a new session with

$_SESSION['user'] = 'foo'; // a static username, and
$_SESSION['pass'] = 'bar'; // a static password.
// If I insert $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'false'; here to start things off, a blank alert box will be returned no matter from where on the page I alert() the value with JS. On the other hand, without this line the same alert will return "1" both here and further down in the script.

if (($_POST['username'] == $_SESSION['user']) && ($_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['pass'])) { // If the username and password filled in before the page reload match the static ones,
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // the user is logged in.
} else { // If there is no match ...
    echo 'Wrong password/username.';
}

include("head.php"); // HTML snippet with everything from the DOCTYPE to the opening BODY tag.

?>
            <div> // HTML interlude ...
<?php

// If the user is logged in, print out a logout button in HTML at the top of the page:

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true)) {
    echo '          <form action="index.php" method="post">';
    echo '            <input type="submit" name="log_out" value="Log out">';
    echo '          </form>';
}

?>
                <p>HTML interlude ...</p>

<?php

// If the user is not logged in, print out a login form in HTML at the bottom of the page:

if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true) {

    echo '            <form action="index.php" method="post">';
    echo '              <label for="username">Username</label><br>';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>';
    echo '              <label for="password">Password</label><br>';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br>';
    echo '              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">';
    echo '            </form>';

}

?>
            </div>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: can you add a snapshot of the output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (($_POST['username'] == $_SESSION['user']) && ($_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['pass'])) { the static ones,
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // the user is logged in.
} else { 
    echo 'Wrong password/username.';
}
```

This part will show "Wrong password/username" when the page loads the first time, because the condition will be false if nothing comes from `$_POST['username']`.

Add the condition `isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])` to both options. Like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    if (($_POST['username'] == $_SESSION['user']) && ($_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['pass'])) { the static ones,
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // the user is logged in.
    } else { 
        echo 'Wrong password/username.';
    }
}
```

This way nothing of this will be evaluated the first time the page loads, but only when credentials have been posted.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend to store the correct username and password in $_SESSION. That is better to get from a database of users for example.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Gustav. Some things are very obvious once someone points them out for you. Now as long as the cookie is cleared I get the login form on page load as expected and no "Wrong password/username." text. However, once I've logged in I can't log out (the logout button is there, but clicking it does nothing) of the session, not even after page reload. (Should I create another question for this?)

Comment: The static username and password is just for testing purposes; I'm gonna try with a database once I get the login functionality working.

Comment: try putting session_start() at the top of the script, and $_SESSION=array(); after session_destroy();

Comment: It works! Actually, all it took was changing the placement of session_start(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, no html, not even a single space, can appear before session_start(), so it's a good convention to put it at the top of the php code, just in case one wants to print stuff from the php..

Answer (score 0):

You find out by debugging your script: Store expectations into variables and print them out, for example:

```
$isLoggedIn = $_SESSION['logged_in']; # Give things a name! (always useful)
echo 'isLoggedIn: ', var_dump($isLoggedIn), "\n"; # debugging
if ($isLoggedIn != true) {

    echo '            <form action="index.php" method="post">';
    echo '              <label for="username">Username</label><br>';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>';
    echo '              <label for="password">Password</label><br>';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br>';
    echo '              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">';
    echo '            </form>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I did some "ugly" debugging with JS alerts -- I'm still at the stage where even if I use the debugger I often don't understand what it's trying to tell me, but of course practice is the only way to get past that.

Comment: JS debugging is different than PHP debugging. For PHP you don't have a console by default.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you load your page then unless you're passing the required post variables, your condition check

```
if (($_POST['username'] == $_SESSION['user']) && ($_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['pass']))
```

will fail, hence the `Wrong password/username.` message showing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! It's so obvious now that I know about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Code looks OK, in fact well done for someone "just learning".

Given that there's nothing obviously wrong with the code (a few rough edges - you should consider using '===' instead of '==' when comparing booleans) then maybe it's the session that's the problem.

Try...

print_r($_SESSION);

immediately after session_start(); and before the condition which chooses whether to display the logout button.

The wrong username message will be displayed every time you *don't* post the parameters to the page as well as when you post the wrong values. Try this:

```
if (($_POST['username'])
    && ($_POST['username'] == $_SESSION['user']) 
    && ($_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['pass'])) {
```

BTW the session is not a good repository for storing usernames and passwords - it's specific to the current user. For a multi-user system these would be stored in a seperate database, e.g.

```
if (($_POST['username']) && lookup($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks @symcbean for the encouraging words and for the tip about print_r() -- I'll be putting that one to good use! Now after testing if the parameter is posted at all, on the first page load there's no error message and no logout button, just the login form like expected, however once logged in I can't log out -- the logout button is there but doesn't do anything. (Like I asked Gustav above, maybe the proper way is to create a new question for this?)